# Create a NFS share between containers described in different docker-compose files and running in different docker-machines

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-machine, nfs

I have the following setup in my computer:

- One `docker-machine` set-up for the containers of my Project A. I have my `docker-compose.yml` file, describing which containers have to be build, the volumes to mount and so on, and the `Dockerfile` for each container.
- Another `docker-machine`set-up for the containers of my Project B, with its `docker-compose.yml` and `Dockerfile`s.

I now want to do a NFS share between a container in my project A (let's call it container 1) and another container in my project B (container 2).

I was checking links like [this](https://forums.docker.com/t/how-to-mount-nfs-drive-in-container-simplest-way/46699/5), but, as far as I understand it, that's for containers in the same network. In this case, my container 1 and container 2 are not in the same network, and they are in different machines.

I haven't specified any networking option when running `docker-machine` or in my `docker-compose.yml` files (apart from exposing the ports that my apps use).

How can I do an NFS share between those 2 containers?

Comment: So you have two different vm machines behind NAT, have you tried using a bridged network for both? You should try to fix this and then tackle the NFS issue.

Answer (score 0):

The 'docker-compose up' command creates a network by name [projectname]_default" and all the services specified in the docker-compose.yml file will be mapped to the network that got created.

For example, suppose your app is in a directory called myapp, and your docker-compose.yml looks like this:

```
 version: "3"
 services:
    web:
      build: .
      ports:
        - "8000:8000"
    db:
      image: postgres
      ports:
         - "8001:5432"
```

When you run docker-compose up, the following happens:

```
 1) A network called myapp_default is created.
 2) A container is created using web’s configuration. It joins the network myapp_default under the name web.
 3) A container is created using db’s configuration. It joins the network myapp_default under the name db.
```

and If you want other service to make use of the existing docker network that is created then you need to define that using 'external' option

### Use a pre-existing network

If you want your containers to join a pre-existing network, use the external option:

```
networks:
   default:
     external:
       name: my-pre-existing-network
```

Instead of attempting to create a network called [projectname]_default, Compose looks for a network called my-pre-existing-network and connect your app’s containers to it.

source: https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/#use-a-pre-existing-network

Comment: I've tried this 'external' option like this: In my project A `docker-compose.yml` file, I've created a network `test`, and added the container I want to said network, and in the project B `docker-compose.yml` file, I've used the external option, but Composer complains, saying that: `Network test declared as external, but could not be found. Please create the network manually using` `docker network create frontback`` and try again.`

Comment: can you please share me the output of 'docker network ls'.